# Withdrawal funds from smart contract

Tags: go-ethereum, metamask, wallets, etherscan, smart-contract-wallets

I made a smart contract using someone else’s  code for running a bot. But when i withdrew the contract the eth is not in my wallet. Where did it go? Please help.

Comment: Could you add the tx hash of the withdraw transaction? Also the source code of the smart contract would be helpful.

Comment: It is very likely you have been scammed, see here for a similar question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/101475/is-this-smart-contract-code-malicious.

Comment: Please at least test the stuff you are going to use/deploy/whatever...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's SCAM. Fromm smartcontract you sent eth to code owners wallet...